# Can you grow raspberries in a pot/growbag?

Tags: containers, raspberries, soft-fruit

Unfortunately we don't have a proper garden, but we do have an area that we can use for pots and/or grow bags. We've been offered some raspberry canes by a friend - but will they grow ok in pots or growbags, or do they need to be in the ground?

I can't seem to find any information online - what would people suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They will grow to a normal size if they are given about 8 cubic feet (2'x2'x2') of good topsoil. Potting soil has to be fertilized more often. Keep them moist and give them at least a half day of sun for best production. You can use grow bags, but pots or planters are more stable and work better long term. I experimented with this and found that I could grow raspberries in pots as small as eight inches, but the smallest pot in which they would grow to a natural size and produce normal amounts of berries held about 8 cubic feet of soil. pot grow brambles are best pruned short (3'). Always prune after temps average under forty degrees Fahrenheit, to reduce the risk of disease. Cut any cane that produced fruit to the ground level, thin out the new canes to the strongest few (6 max.) and cut those canes and any branches on them to tree feet of the ground.